# Google Script ui.button calling prompt from other function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two separate scripts that are activated by buttons in a sheet. One sends an email (CALemail.js), and the other clears cells (clear.js). Both scripts prompt for confirmation before running. While the first one executes perfectly, my clear.js script first asks the prompt from CALemail and then asks the clear.js prompt before running. How can I separate them?

CALemail.js:

```
    var ehtml =  
    '<body>' + 
      '<h2>Calendar Updated</h2>' +
        '<p>You can access it by <a href="http://example.com">clicking here</a> </p>' +

    '</body>'   


 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

 var response = ui.alert('You are sending a link to the current version of this calendar. Do you want to continue?', 
ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);



 if (response == ui.Button.YES) function CALemail() {


  MailApp.sendEmail(
    'example@gmail.com',         // recipient
    ' Calendar Updated',                  // subject 
    'test', {                        // body
      htmlBody: ehtml                 // advanced options


    } );
} else {

}
```

clear.js:

```
function clearRange() {

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert('STOP! You are attempting to clear the Calendar. THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE. Do you want to continue?', 
ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Calendar');


 if (response == ui.Button.YES)

{

   sheet.getRange('B4:V10').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B12:V18').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B20:V26').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B28:V34').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B36:V42').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B44:C50').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('D3:D43').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('G3:G43').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('J3:J43').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M3:M43').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('P3:P43').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('S3:S43').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('V3:V43').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B53:V65').clearContent();
 }
 }
```

Comment: You need to wrap them each in function wrappers `function funcname(){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you put them in separate files or in the same file, they need to be separate functions. Unless you want the to run every time you access a function.

```
function testEmail(){
  var ehtml =  '<body><h2>Calendar Updated</h2><p>You can access it by <a href="http://example.com">clicking here</a> </p></body>';
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('You are sending a link to the current version of this calendar. Do you want to continue?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if(response == ui.Button.YES) function CALemail() {
    MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com',' Calendar Updated','test',{htmlBody: ehtml});
   }
}

function clearRange(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('STOP! You are attempting to clear the Calendar. THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE. Do you want to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Calendar');
  if (response == ui.Button.YES){
    sheet.getRange('B4:V10').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('B12:V18').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('B20:V26').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('B28:V34').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('B36:V42').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('B44:C50').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('D3:D43').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('G3:G43').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('J3:J43').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('M3:M43').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('P3:P43').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('S3:S43').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('V3:V43').clearContent();
    sheet.getRange('B53:V65').clearContent();
  }
}
```

Note: I didn't test them nor do I care too.  That's upto you.